# Mssql connection to SQL Server on Parallels Desktop

Tags: sql-server, virtual-machine, parallels

few days ago I set up a connection via php using *mssql_connect()* to my SQL Server on Parallels Desktop (running Windows 7). Everything was working perfectly, until I updated my mac to OS X Yosemite, and Parallels Desktop too. Now, I keep getting this error:

```
Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

I recently installed Apache server on Windows and I'm able to connect from Mac's browser, so I really don't understand what's going on..

This is what I already tried:

- reinstalling Parallels
- reinstalling SQL Server (setting everything like before: enabling TCP connection for SQL Server, adding rule for port 1433 in Firewall)
- disabling firewall

but still nothing... Anyone having this connection problem with Parallels Desktop?

If this could help anyone in identifying the problem, I just tried to telnet with command: *telnet ipaddress 1433*. I successfully connect, but still get the same error from PHP.

Should I try sqlsrv_connect()?

Comment: offtopic, not really a programming question. But probably something changed in the networking setup and your virtual win7 isn't reachable anymore.

Comment: This is why I tried to install Apache server, to check if Windows was reachable on any other port...and it is.